# Close current tab in the browser on save later button in Angular 7 application

Tags: angular

My requirement is on click of the save & later button it should close the application that is currently opened tab in the browser but it not working `window.close()` and some other hacks not working can anyone suggest 
how to implement it is Angular 7 application

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Put some codes and ask question in a proper way for easy understanding of audiences.

Answer (score 0):

## Try:-

```
<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="self.close()">
```

or,

```
<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="CloseWindow();">

CloseWindow(){
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
}
```